# Read proprietary EXIF data from image

Tags: python, exif

I need to get non-standard EXIF tags from an image, such as `Gimbal Pitch Degree`. I have so far not found a Python EXIF library that would allow me to get this tag and have to rely on invoking system-level ExifTool:

```
gimbal_pitch_degree = subprocess.Popen(
    ['exiftool', photo_path, '-gimbalpitchdegree'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE
).communicate()[0]
```

Is there any way to read the raw data? I'm willing to parse it out if I get all the tags, but I want to avoid having to have a system-wide binary available for the script.

Comment: I would suggest that you just fork and edit any of Python EXIF libraries to handle your special format. Usually they are not that large and are easily understandable.

Comment: It seems that venerable old PIL can do it: https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/python/PIL/ExifTags.html